# Comparar meses y años Fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

He estado batallando con un proceso es simple pero me he bloqueado.

Quisiera tener el rango de meses y años entre dos fechas en SQL Server.

Ejemplo:

*Fecha Inicial: 2020-12-01* (1 de Diciembre de 2019)

*Fecha Final: 2021-02-01* (1 de febrero de 2021)

Resultado Salida:

```
2020-12-01
2021-01-01
2021-02-01
```

He andado buscando en internet y solo aparecen resultados de la diferencia mediante DATEDIFF pero como tal la fecha no he podido encontrar una forma.

Comment: La diferencia entre dos fechas no es otra fecha.

Comment: Vos queres que magicamente SQL genere datos que no existen? o esto sale de una tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una función para que te resulte más fácil.

```
Create function dbo.fn_TiL_MonthsInPeriod 
(
@fechaAct date,
@fechaSig date
)
returns table
return
with c1 as (
    select tbl.n from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))
 tbl(n)
    ), c2 as (select 1 as c from c1 cross join c1 as t
    ), c3 as (select 1 as c from c2 cross join c2 as t
    ), c4 as (select 1 as c from c3 cross join c3 as t
    ), Nums as (select row_number() 
over(order by (select null)) as rownum from c4)
    , interval as
    (
    select top(datediff(MONTH,@fechaact, @fechasig)) 
       rownum as n
    from nums
    )
    select
        dateadd(MONTH,n-1,@fechaact) as [month]
    from interval
    union all
    Select @fechasig;
```

La misma utiliza una serie de filas creadas al vuelo, retornando la diferencia en meses entre lo pasado como parámetro de inicio y final.

Su utilización sería:

```
DECLARE @FECHAINICIAL DATE = '20201201'
DECLARE @FECHAFINAL DATE = '20210201'
SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.fn_TiL_MonthsInPeriod(@fechainicial, @fechafinal) fn;
```

[image: Res]

Tienes más detalles de como se puede hacer, en este hilo, donde se hace lo mismo para días.

Incluso puedes reconvertirla para que te sirva para cualquier parte de una fecha, pues al final, usa la función dateDiff, y solo habría que tener en cuenta la parte a aplicar.

[Dias entre dos fechas.](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/04/todos-los-dias-en-un-intervalo/)

Answer (score -1):

Exactamente no tengo claro para qué puedas necesitar esta funcionalidad, sin embargo, para propósitos generales crear un procedimiento almacenado puede serte de utilidad, ya que, con las funciones del sistema para restar fechas no obtendrás lo que requieres.

Para ello este SP te puede ayudar:

```sql
create procedure devolverdiff_fechas @fcha1 datetime,
                                     @fcha2 datetime
as
  begin
      declare @repeticiones int = Datediff(month, @fcha1, @fcha2)
      declare @contador int = 0
      declare @tabla_final table
        (
           fecha varchar(max)
        )
      declare @ultimo_mes_fcha1 int = Month(@fcha1)
      declare @anio_a_colocar int = Year(@fcha1)

      insert into @tabla_final
      values     (Cast(@anio_a_colocar as varchar) + '-'
                  + Cast(@ultimo_mes_fcha1 as varchar) + '-'
                  + Cast(Day(@fcha1) as varchar))

      while @contador < @repeticiones
        begin
            if @ultimo_mes_fcha1 = 12
              begin
                  set @ultimo_mes_fcha1 = 1
                  set @anio_a_colocar += 1
              end
            else
              begin
                  set @ultimo_mes_fcha1 += 1
              end

            insert into @tabla_final
            values     (Cast(@anio_a_colocar as varchar) + '-'
                        + Cast(@ultimo_mes_fcha1 as varchar) + '-'
                        + Cast(Day(@fcha1) as varchar))

            set @contador+=1
        end

      select *
      from   @tabla_final
  end
```

Breve explicación:

- `@repeticiones`: es la diferencia de meses que será igual al nro de filas en la tabla final.
- `@contador`: servirá para iterar.
- `@tabla_final`: el resultado final en tipo de dato table.
- `@ultimo_mes_fcha1`: sirve para detectar si es diciembre, en caso lo sea cambia de año.
- `@anio_a_colocar:` el año que se colocará en la tabla final.

Luego, el proceso es simple, si el último mes es 12 entonces cambia el año y el último mes será 1, al final del bucle se insertarán los datos en la tabla. Algo a tomar en cuenta es que antes que inicie el `while`, ya se habría insertado la fecha 1.

La salida final con otro ejemplo al tuyo sería:

```sql
exec devolverDIFF_fechas '2020-09-05', '2021-02-05'
```

```sql
+-----------+
| fecha     |
+-----------+
| 2020-9-5  |
| 2020-10-5 |
| 2020-11-5 |
| 2020-12-5 |
| 2021-1-5  |
| 2021-2-5  |
+-----------+
```

> Te dejo la <kbd>[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/ly2-u_9i)</kbd> para que pruebas probarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Para obtener datos consecutivos en SQL, lo ideal es usar una tabla de números (o *tally table* como se le conoce en inglés). Esta tabla nos permite evitar muchas estructuras de bucles que son ineficientes en SQL.

Podemos crear una tabla al vuelo que no requiere lecturas de datos y vive enteramente en memoria. El siguiente ejemplo genera una tabla con 10,000 números o filas.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Esta estructura se puede ajustar para el problema en cuestión.

```
DECLARE @FechaInicial   date = '20201201',
        @FechaFinal     date = '20210201';

WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para más de 800 años)
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteFechas(fecha) AS(
    SELECT TOP ( DATEDIFF( MM, @FechaInicial, @FechaFinal) + 1) --Limitamos las filas a la amplitud del rango
        DATEADD( MM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @FechaInicial)  fecha --generamos las fechas con base en la fecha inicial
    FROM E4
)
SELECT fecha
FROM cteFechas;
```

Pero como obviamente no queremos escribir todo el código una y otra vez, lo convertimos en una función.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GeneraMesesEnRango(
    @FechaInicial   date = '20201201',
    @FechaFinal     date = '20210201'
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para más de 800 años)
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteFechas(fecha) AS(
    SELECT TOP ( DATEDIFF( MM, @FechaInicial, @FechaFinal) + 1) --Limitamos las filas a la amplitud del rango
        DATEADD( MM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @FechaInicial)  fecha --generamos las fechas con base en la fecha inicial
    FROM E4
)
SELECT fecha
FROM cteFechas;
```

De tal forma, solo tenemos que llamar la función cada vez que se requiera ya sea por su cuenta o incluyendola en una consulta más amplia.

```
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.GeneraMesesEnRango( @FechaInicial, @FechaFinal) m

SELECT *
FROM  AlgunaTabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.GeneraMesesEnRango( t.FechaInicial, t.FechaFinal) m
```